# Scala actors with concurrent acces to shared cache of objects, scala.concurrent.Lock, react vs receive

Tags: scala, shared-memory, actor, locks

I'm writing a soft in which various actors concurrently create portions of a same graph.

Nodes of the graph are modeled through a class hierarchy, each concrete class of the hierarchy has a companion object.

```
    abstract class Node
    class Node1(k1:Node, k2:Node) extends Node
    object Node1 {
      def apply(k1:Node, k2:Node) = ...
    }
    class Node2(k1:Node, k2:Node) extends Node
    object Node2 {
      def apply(k1:Node, k2:Node) = ...
    }
    ...
```

So far so good.

We perfom structural hashing on the nodes on creation.
That is, each companion object has a HashTable which stores node instances keyed under their constructor arguments, this is used to detect that an instance of a given node class with the same subnodes already exists and to return that one instead of creating a new instance. This allows to avoid memory blowup, and allows have a node equality test that takes constant time (reference comparison instead of graph comparison). Access to this map is protected using a scala.concurrent.Lock.

Yet the problem is that the Lock operate at jvm thread level, and that depending on how actors are coded, they can either be allocated on their own jvm threads, or instead be interleaved with several other actors in a same JVM thread in which case the structural hashing ceases to work (i.e., several structurally identical nodes can be created, and only one of them will be stored in the cache, and the structural equality will cease to work).

First, I know that this structural hashing architecture goes against the actor share-nothing philosophy, but we really need this hashing to work for performance reasons (constant time equality brings us an order of magnitude improvement), but is there a way to implement mutual exclusion on shared ressources with actors that would work at actor level rather than jvm thread level?

I thought of encapsulating the node companion in an actor to completely sequentialize access to the factory but this would imply a complete rewrite of all the existing code, any other idea?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you need more code in your question. Where is the Map, how do you access it from actors?

Answer (score 0):

If you have shared mutable state,  have a single actor which mutates this state.  You can have other actors read, but have one actor that does the writes.